# Django how to add data to Object from queryset

Tags: python, django, django-views

I would like show list of clients and show tags assigned to them but I have problem because I have my tags in other table and I dont know how to connect data together. Clients can have couple of tags or none of that. Which way is correct to do this? Can you advice me something? I need one variable with tags separated comma or objects with tags which I can use in template engine.

**Views.py:**

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff, login_url='/account/login/')
def client_list(request):
    dict = {}
    dict['clients'] = Client.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'panel/client/list.html', dict)
```

**Models.py:**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)

class TagsClientChoices(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)

class TagsClientList(models.Model):
    tag_id = models.ForeignKey('TagsClientChoices')
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Is your question just how to access a one-to-many model?...

Comment: No is not my question. I would like show list of all clients adding to every one client him tags which are saved in TagsClientList. It's not OneToOneField because i dont have connect in Client model to TagsClientList. In short i need tags based on client_id and show it but i don't know how connect these without adding field in model.

Comment: [Many-to-one-relationships.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default every foreignkey has a reverse relation with _set

so you could do

```
for client in clients:
    for taglist in client.tagsclientlist_set.all():
        # use taglist
```

Although this may not be very performant, you may want to [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) and provide a related_name which will retrieve the results in two queries rather than multiple.

```
class TagsClientList(models.Model):
    tag_id = models.ForeignKey('TagsClientChoices')
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client', blank=True, null=True, related_name='tags_list')



dict['clients'] = Client.objects.all().prefetch_related('tags_list')

for client in clients:
    for taglist in client.tags_list.all():
        # use taglist
```

Comment: Note: You don't need a `related_name` for the `prefetch_related` to work, the `_set` reverse relation will also work

Comment: `prefetch_related` will cause **two** database queries to be run, but it's definitely more performant.

Comment: @rnevius - Thanks! Misread the docs slightly, (It mentions "single query" repeatedly but is actually only referring to the fk lookup)

Comment: Thanks for clever solution but I gor error "Manager isn't accessible via TagsClientList instances" when I'm trying create another for inside taglist for :(

Comment: @Thaian - That sounds like a separate unrelated issue, you should make a new question complete with what you have tried/researched.