# how to efficiently use _set.all() in django?

Tags: python, django, optimization, reverse-lookup

Is there a way in django to do the following more efficiently when the number Entry objects is greater than 5000 entries?

models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.TextField(db_column='User', blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

class Color(models.Model):
    color = models.TextField(blank=True)
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
```

And let's say that I wanted to get all the colors for each of these entries...

```
entrys = Entry.objects.all()

for e in entrys:
    print e.color_set.all()
```

I want to be able to relate each object to a specific entry. For example, in a csv table like this.

```
user, color
john, blue
john, orange
bob, green
bob, red
bob, purple
```

It takes several seconds to look through all of my entries. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can go other way around. Get all the Color objects and order them by `entry` and then iterate.

Comment: You can use `prefetch_related` as per [an answer I just made on a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35893764/1324033)

Comment: To extend @Sayse comment, `selected_related` could also be an option. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related You basically want to do an eager load.

Comment: @themanatuf - `select_related` isn't an option since that doesn't work for one-to-many

Comment: @Sayse yes, you're right, but if the orig poster follows what @AKS suggested, then `select_related` would work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
entrys = Entry.objects.all().prefetch_related('color_set')

for e in entrys:
    print e.color_set.all()
```

Instead of doing n, queries it will do 2, one for the entries, and one for the foreign key lookups

Comment: This does not seem to run much faster... Am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnWaller - I'm not sure, its possible that the time issue is no longer on a database side, but maybe just taking a while to print out the values or whatever the csv part of your question was referring to

Comment: @JohnWaller - Of course, you are still trying to return quite a large number of records from your database so there must be some time involved there

Answer (score 2):

As I commented earlier, if you just need all the colors of an `Entry` together, you can select all the `Color` objects and order them on `entry`:

```
colors = Color.objects.order_by('entry')
```

Now, you can loop over these objects and print them the way you want:

```
for color in colors:
    print(color.entry.user, color.color)

# john, blue
# john, orange
# bob, green
```

Or, you can extract this information as `values_list`

```
color_entries = list(colors.values_list('entry__user', 'color'))
# [('john', 'blue'), ('john', 'orange'), ('bob', 'green'), ...]
```

Comment: What if I have another model that is also related to entry and I wanted those values too?

Comment: This will still create n (5000) queries since it will retrieve the `entry` on every iteration.

Comment: But if you use `values_list` it will be efficient. Or, am I missing something with `values_list`?

Comment: It will be more efficient for a different reason, since it will be selecting the certain values instead of `*`

Comment: And, isn't that what exactly the OP asked for :)

Comment: It results in a different query though since you no longer have the objects

Comment: I agree. And, I like your answer better. I Was just trying to provide an alternative way and limiting it to the example provided in the question.